# Get a list of all duplicates in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get all the duplicates in a column. The column is currently sorted. I believe this will need to be a macro(maybe a function) so it can add the duplicate values to another column. I want to paste a range of cells in column A and have column B give me the duplicates. Example below.

Column A

> SD1000023
>
> SD1000024
>
> SD1000024
>
> SD1000025
>
> SD1000026
>
> SD1000026
>
> SD1000027

Then my column would have:

Column B

> SD1000024
>
> SD1000026

From [`here`](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/22/extract-a-list-of-duplicates-from-a-column-using-array-formula-in-excel/) I found this, just not sure how to fix it for my needs. I don't understand the `list1` part.

```
=INDEX(List1, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(C1:$C$1, List1)+IF(COUNTIF(List1, List1)>1, 0, 1), 0))
```

Comment: List1 is the *Name* of the range that contains the values on which you are operating. In that example, List1 refers to the cells A2:A20. For new lists, you just re-define the range.

Comment: @EmacsUser, I am somewhat familiar with `CountIf` the first param is the range and the second param is the expression to look for - why is it the range used again as the expression in this example above?

Comment: can you point to where under "How this array formula works" on that page  since List1 is used 4 times and I'm not sure which expression you are referring to.

Comment: First - I don't see where `List1` is defined, in my brain that needs to occur. Second - If it's just the range I have replaced the `List1` with the range and I cannot get the function to work. Thanks

Comment: List1 is defined on page 1 of that 2-page article you referenced.

Comment: Ok, I did not see that page. I don't think is going to work for me either. I simple want to paste a range of cells in column A and have column B give me the duplicates.

Comment: You have to enter a formula first. Excel can't do it any simpler.

Comment: It would, there would be a blank excel sheet (saved file)- minus the formula in one cell. I open the file paste the data and function just runs. Macro would be fine as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82982/discussion-between-emacs-user-and-onefineday).

Comment: Can you tell me how large of data sets you will be looking at? Barring very large sets, an array loop can do this very quickly.

Comment: No more that 2500 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Remove Duplicates" application in the Data Tab.  First, Copy Column A, paste into Column B.  Then choose Data -> Remove Duplicates and select Column B (don't extend to Column A when asked).  Then click "Ok", this will leave you with a list of unique values.  Then, of those, to see which have duplicates, you could (in column C), do "=Countif(B1,A:A)" to see how many times that value occurs in the list.

Here's a macro that should get you going.  Note, I assume that you have a header row, if not you just need to tweak slightly:

```
Sub List_Duplicates()
Dim lastRow As Integer, dataCol As Integer, duplicateCol As Integer, lastUniqueRow As Integer
Dim dataRng As Range, dupRng As Range
Dim ws            As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row    'This assumes your Column A has no line breaks, if it does, comment this out and use below
    'lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    dataCol = 1              'if your list of data, including duplicates, is in COlumn A
    duplicateCol = 2         'where to put the duplicate number

    Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(2, dataCol), .Cells(lastRow, dataCol))
    Set dupRng = .Range(.Cells(2, duplicateCol), .Cells(lastRow, duplicateCol))

    'First, we will copy the Column A data to column B
    dupRng.Value = dataRng.Value

    'Now, remove duplicates from this

    lastUniqueRow = .Cells(2, duplicateCol).End(xlDown).Row
    dupRng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    'Evaluate the countif formula, and then leave duplicates in col. B
    Dim i         As Integer
    For i = 2 To lastUniqueRow 'This will loop through our duplicate cells, and remove any that are not duplicates
        If .Cells(i, duplicateCol).Row > lastUniqueRow Then Exit For
        Debug.Print .Cells(i, duplicateCol).Value & " occurrs " & Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRng, .Cells(i, duplicateCol))) & " times."
        If Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRng, .Cells(i, duplicateCol))) <= 1 Then
            .Cells(i, duplicateCol).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
    dupRng.Select
    dupRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete
End With
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions! And if anyone else has any comments or suggestions for the above, kindly let me know so I can learn too :P

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something more automatic than doing all those steps every time I need to do this.

Comment: I need a list of duplicates not the unique ones - or did I miss something in your example?

Comment: If you do the "Countif" formula, it'll tell you how many times each record shows in your original list.  So, anything that shows 2 or more is a duplicate.  Then you can just delete the ones that aren't duplicates.

If all this works for you, I can write something for VBA so you have it as a macro.

Comment: I am totally happy with a macro.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Assuming that the data starts in A1, In B1 enter

```
=IF(A1 = A2, A1,"")
```

And in B2 enter

```
=IF(AND(A2<>A1,A2 = A3),A2,"")
```

And copy this formula the rest of the way down B. This will cause the duplicated values to appear in column B exactly once. You can then copy them and paste them back in place as values, and then sort the result to get what you want gathered into adjacent cells.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional format column A for duplicates. This macro will then label all duplicates in column B.

```
Sub dup()

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> 16777215 Then
Cells(i, 2) = "Dup"
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the column next to it, you can use the formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)` and filter on anything not equal to 1